# show sub categories actual category

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

```
class Category(models.Model):
   parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self',related_name='child_category_list',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
   name            = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   cat_id         = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
   path            = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)


def pre_save_parent_category(sender,instance,**kwargs):
   instance.path = instance.name
   parent_category_obj = instance.parent_category
   while parent_category_obj is not None:
      instance.path = parent_category_obj.name + " > " + instance.path
      parent_category_obj = parent_category_obj.parent_category

pre_save.connect(pre_save_parent_category,sender=Category)
```

I have numerous categories if user input category id how can i show the sub categories of that category

Answer (score 0):

serializers.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Category
      fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class SubCategoryAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
   serializer_class = CategorySerializer
   queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent_category__cat_id='171146')
```